# How can i add image to Jodit after Upload

Tags: reactjs, jodit

I have successfully uploaded Image to backend using Jodit with this Property.

```
"uploader": {
  url: 'http://localhost:3001/knowledgebase/upload',      
}
```

Now I want that uploaded image to be displayed in the Jodit Editor for that i am passing url for uploaded image from back end to front end as a response. But how can I make an image element with src="response-url from backend"

Note: I am using Jodit in React.