Unable to upload image in jodit editor in react
I want to run my custom image upload handler. Jodit editor gives a flag for image upload which is "insertImageAsBase64URI". If this flag is false, image upload option from editor disappears. But for custom handler, you have to make this flag false according to documentation. Following is my configurations for jodit editor on which image upload works:
const config = {
    readonly: false,
    height: 400,
   uploader: {
      insertImageAsBase64URI: true,
   }
};



I need help with how to make configurations of jodit editor as I am new to it and I cannot find proper help online which can solve my issue.
I want to run my own function of image uploader which return the image url.
  const imageUploadHandler = (blobInfo?: any, success?: any, failure?: any) => {
   
   // I want to enter this function because it returns the url of image.

  };

Basically, I want to call my image upload handler while uploading image and insert image URL on editor instead of image. Jodit editor configuration are causing me issues. As soon as I make the image flag turns false to write my own process, image upload option disappears. I have even tried following solution which tells how to use custom url image upload.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77735921/how-can-i-add-image-to-jodit-after-upload
But it doesn't work.
